# How can I rearrange elements in this way from mobile to desktop on this web page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to write a responsive web page that will rearrange elements according to this image:

http://imgur.com/RELwGie

The elements are arranged in the same order in the HTML as they are on the mobile layout. On the desktop layout, the left side and right sides will both fill 50% of the window width.

I've tried using:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Which works until there's not enough elements on the left side, so elements floated left end up going on the right side.

So my question is how can I create a responsive layout like in the image and how can I keep the elements I want on the left and right to stay in their correct locations.

Comment: Offhand I can't think of any layout method (other than CSS Grid which isn't supported yet) that could do this...**maybe** flexbox with some re-reordering. Interesting.

Comment: Your best solutin, even though what you are asking makes no sense(I bet is a client who's asking you to do that), would be to use jquery.

Comment: Using float:right to the 2nd element helps?http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVEvWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float values left and right as you need. Hope this helps to give an idea

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVEvWN

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="a">1</div>
  <div id="b">2</div>
  <div id="c">3</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="d">4</div>
    <div id="e">5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="f">6</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  width: 500px;
  background: #eee;
}
#d {
  background: #c3ffaa;
}
#d, #e {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles only for big screen. Use current styling for mobiles. */
#a {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}

#b {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  height: 60px;
}
#c {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background: #a321c2;
}
.wrap {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
#d {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: #c3ffaa;
}
#e {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
}
```